# C# using dynamic for both decimal and double

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods

I have an assignment where the I gotta figure out a way to make the input read both `double` and `decimal` and perform a few operations as new method.

```
char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ' ' };

Console.Write("Please type few numbers: ");
dynamic[] test = Console.ReadLine().Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

dynamic value = test[0];
for (int i = 1; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    if (test[i] < value)
    {
        value = test[i];
    }
}
```

I figured out to use `dynamic` as data type, but this throws an exception:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
```

I already made a fallback using a `switch` where the user selects if it's `double` or `decimal` but I thought this was way more simple.

How to stop that `dynamic` from being read as `string` ?

Comment: `dynamic` is a sign to the compiler to "defer checks" until runtime. It doesn't change the type automatically for you. You need to convert it to either a `decimal` or a `double` in the first place. `var` won't work either since you are always reading a string.

Comment: `value` is a string because you obtain it from `string.Split`. You'll need to use one of the various `decimal` and `double` parse options to convert those strings to numeric values.

Comment: Do not use `dynamic`. C# != php.

Comment: Can I ask *why* you need both double and decimal? `Console.ReadLine()` will only ever read in a string to which you can parse however you want (not many reasons to ever need to use both decimal and double for one input)

Comment: Your idea to use `dynamic` is probably wrong here. Can you give us a complete assignment text, so we don't have to guess what would *input both `double` and `decimal`* means and in what context?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var value=  Convert.ToDecimal( test[0])
```

or

```
var value= Convert.ToDouble( test[0])
```

because test[0] is a string, so when you define it as dynamic, its type binds in run time but makes no difference because its type is clear in compile-time and no need to define it as dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the split method always returns an array of strings, so you have to convert it results. The problem isn't the Dynamic.

Example:

char[] charSeparators = new char[] { ' ' };

```
    Console.Write("Please type few numbers: ");
    dynamic[] test = Console.ReadLine().Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

    double value = double.Parse(test[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        if (double.Parse(test[i]) < value)
        {
            value = double.Parse(test[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the console input which will be a string. In order to turn in into any sort of numeric value you need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic[] test = Console.ReadLine().Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();` will be a string array, so you'll need to cast it to a decimal or a double.

I'm not sure how you're going to figure out whether it's double of decimal, so why not cast them all to decimal, since that type keeps its precision.

Answer (score 0):

Your current array contains strings. You need to convert them to decimals or doubles

```
dynamic[] test = Console.ReadLine().Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray().Select(double.Parse).ToArray();
```